# How to enable Ant development in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, ant

I have installed eclipse (with ADT). I am unable to execute (No option under Run as) one Ant build xml file and also there is no option under preference to make it available.

I went through preferences but i did not find "Capabilities" option under General. 
Window - Preferences - General - Capabilities - Advanced - Development.

Do i need to install some thing else as a plugin??

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Look in Run > External Tools > External Tools Configurations...

Comment: I checked but no related run configuration available there.

Comment: Bear in mind that Google has dropped both Ant and Eclipse. For command-line work, I strongly encourage you to use Gradle for Android.

Comment: What's your OS ? Linux, Mac, Windows ?

Comment: see => https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=73427

Comment: Thanks rebse, This post helped out. Issue resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Following solution worked out for me.

1. Help -> Install New SoftWare
2. Work With -> "http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno"
3. Drop down list "General Purpose Tools"
4. select "Eclipse Plug-in Development Environment"

Reference :   https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=73427

Answer (score 0):

I was doing my Spring Frameworks study course which required I do a right-click > Run As > Ant Build on a file, and that option didn't exist. I managed to overcome this by opening the Ant view (Window > Show View > Ant), then inside the Ant View right-click and add the file from where I was able to run the required target. I am running on Eclipse Kepler SR2 (4.3.2).